# Form Input - Restricting to one submit per IP / Computer

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, cookies, ip-address

I'm coding a sweepstakes entry form in php where the User submits some information in a form and it is stored in a database.

I would like to find a way to restrict this form to one submission per person. Either dropping a cookie or by IP address. What would be the best way to approach this?

I'm building it on code igniter, if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple answer, log the IP in the same row with the information store. If you do a cookie a bot or user can easily remove the cookie destroying your protection scheme. So simply log the IP address and then query each entry for uniqueness before accepting the submission.

Answer (score 1):

They both have their own downsides tbh. Cookies are easy to forge and easy to remove which will allow multiple votes. Restricting by IP is better but IP addresses can be shared within networks and can also be proxied to avoid detection. Best bet is rely on something like email address and force the user to click an emailed link to confirm a vote, admittedly though this isn't great.

Answer (score 1):

There are several methods you can use to mitigate against casual cheating.  In my view you should not expect to be able to stop a determined cheater without a more formal validation process (cc authorization..etc).

The easiest approach is to ask for a residential address to send goods when they win :)

First and foremost deny the cheater any feedback channel to be able to tell if their submission was accepted or rejected.  If there is a slight delay for accepted entries make sure you add a fake delay with some jitter so they can't tell if their scheme for thwarting your anti-cheating method worked or even if you have any anti-cheating methods at all.  Detecting bulk submissions by a cheater are much easier when they don't feel they need to be creative.

IP Address as you mentioned.  Perhaps use geoip, whois..etc to get distributions over time WRT area.

User agent and system fingerprinting - there is a huge amount of information you can get from the browser that may or may not be unique. Browser type, version, operating system, screen resolution, color depth, installed fonts, plugins (flash, pdf, java...etc) and associated version numbers, language, browsers local time (log client clock skew)

Use of cookies, perhaps hide references to an innocent sounding domain in an included javascript you also control.  This may be used to correlate the manual deletion of obvious cookies with the hidden cookies.  Its less known that cookies can also be stored in separate databases of other plugins the user may have such as flash player.  These are NOT removed when the browser cookies are deleted.

Use of images with cache headers.  The first time a user visits the site display an image after their entry is submitted.  If they've already filled out the form and they submit again the image would be cached and you can use the absence of the image request to assume submitted entries are a result of cheating.

Answer (score 0):

Why not drop both.  Throw a cookie on the user's machine.  Then, in a database keep a field with an ip address.  That way, if they have different ip addresses (due to certain internet company configs), the cookie can catch it.  The database field will serve to be more secure and a backup if people don't allow cookies.  These solutions will not be 100% foolproof, however, because if a person had changing ip addresses and doesn't allow cookies, you could run into problems.  I would check for cookies being enabled to get around this.  Try to set a cookie and read it.  If you can, you're good to go.  Otherwise, prompt them to allow cookies.

Best of luck

Comment: not that a cookie is bad, but any novice sweepstake scammer will immediately check and erase cookies between spams, its pretty much the oldest trick in the book.

Answer (score 0):

To add to the others, you could require a login/signup to vote.

Answer (score 0):

As stated by others cookies are easy to fake / delete. The client IP seen for a single user can change even mid session, and there may be thousands of users sharing the same client address.

Email addresses are harder to forge - and you can add a verification stage to the process - its information you need to capture anyway - but do keep track of the user agent and client address each submission originates from and is verified from - then you can make a smart determination about the winner instead of trying to check every submission.

C.